# How to show indentation guides in TextMate

Tags: textmate, indentation

How do I show indentation guides in TextMate?

Anyone knows if there is a bundle for this? There's no setting, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is as close to an answer as we are going to get for now:

A bundle that may or may not work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463270/column-indentation-guide-on-textmate

Current progress on this issue for Textmate 2:
https://github.com/textmate/textmate/pull/945

Answer (score 4):

There is a menu item somewhere, or a preference settings called "show invisible characters".

That's what is used in TextMate to show indentation levels: you get a little gray triangle at each tab.

I'm sorry if I'm not more precise, I'm on my linux box at home. But I'm sure you'll find it easily.

**EDIT:**

The menu item is labeled "Show Invisibles", it's located under the "View" menu and its shortcut is <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah, I think thats as close as it gets. Thanks.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In TextMate 2, select:

```
View > Show Indent Guides
View > Hide Indent Guides
```

Which was added via this commit:
https://github.com/textmate/textmate/commit/263da53c8166273859c91c1a88ef2157d1d05ca8

[image: TextMate Indent Guides]

Answer (score 1):

If this ticket is still open, then I don't think there is a way to show indentation guides.

http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=0DC672CD